# Repeat label in a pivot table but add unique identifier

Tags: excel

I'm trying to add a unique identifier in my pivot table.

Say you have this:

```
Apple                4
Orange               2
Apple                3
Orange               9
Banana               8
```

With item and quantity representing the labels respectively.

If you throw this in a pivot table and repeat labels, it would be re-arrange in alphabetical order (or really however you set it up). I want it to do this:

```
Apple-1   4
Apple-2   3
etc
```

Using the repeat item labels doesn't add this. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like this totally defeats the purpose of a pivot table, which is to summarize the underlying data. Well, maybe you have other fields that distinguish `Apple-1` from `Apple-2`. In any case, I'm not sure of any native method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your item list alphabetically

[image]

2. Create a new table, in the first column, use the following formula:

   ```
   =A2 & "-" & COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
   ```
3. In the second one, siomply use `=B2`
4. Populate down

[image]

Comment: I'll play with this. Is there a way to 'create a connection' between a pivot table and another table? The pivot table is from data that gets re-generated nightly.